# How do you create an instance of phantomJS with a custom window.navigator object?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, headless-browser

How can a custom window.navigator object be applied to PhantomJS's WebPage object during creation? When I attempt to customize the navigator, I'm still receiving the default value when I `console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);`

What I have so far:

```
console.log('hello');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    var newNavigator = Object.create(window.navigator);
    newNavigator.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36';
    window.navigator = newNavigator;
  });
};
page.open('http://www.google.com', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
}});
```

The contents of the console when running the above js:

```
hello
The default user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34
(KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34
^C
```

Comment: Uh, why not just assign to the `page.settings`? Don't expect that any in-site modifications/overwritings to native object will be reflect in your settings objects.

Comment: @Bergi per the phantomjs documentation, any changes to the page.settings made anytime other than during the WebPage#Open function, are ignored. This is why I'm attempting to tie it into the OnInitialized callback. How do I do this? https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need and cannot use `evaluate` to set the navigator. You can just set via settings. So the following works for me on phantomjs 1.9.7:

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36';
};
```

**Output**

```
hello
The default user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
^C
```